# How can I open the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator in Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, odbc

I want to add 32-bit data sources. There seems to be no obvious way to see existing instances of these or create new ones.

How can I open the 32-bit "ODBC Data Source Administrator" window in Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: On my version of Windows (10 pro), a shortcut to *ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)* is included in the *Windows Administrative Tools* folder (along with the 64-bit version, and things like Computer Management, Services, etc.)

Comment: Why on earth did they remove the shortcut to open the 32-bit version from the Administrative Tools folder? On my old Windows XP x64 computer there were shortcuts to open both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions...

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Run the Datasource editor from this path `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.

Ref: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/farukcelik/why-my-32-bit-applications-cannot-see-the-odbc-dsns-that-i-created-on-my-64-bit-machine)

Comment: Zoredache, still helpful years later! Thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: Worthy of note: if you have the 64 bit version already open, running the command for the 32bit does **not** open a second ODBC window and  puts the 64bit window into focus.

Answer (score 23):

Just a small note to [Zorodache answer](https://superuser.com/a/419833/283616), if you use the search box from the **start menu** type the **whole path** to get the correct version `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`.

Otherwise, you will get the 64-bit version, even if you enter `odbcad32.exe` in the search box.

Comment: This should be upvoted more!

Comment: @DenysVitali except, apparently, if you put the whole path in the search box, you _still_ only get the 64-bit version. I ended up having to open a command window

Comment: Seriously? Really strange... but I'm not surprised anymore when Windows is involved...

Comment: @Auspex for me it works entering the full path c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Answer (score 5):

A 64-bit version of the Microsoft Windows operating system includes the following versions of the Microsoft Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) Data Source Administrator tool (Odbcad32.exe):

- The 32-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the
  %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64 folder.
- The 64-bit version of the
  Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\System32
  folder.

The Odbcad32.exe file displays the following types of data source names (DSNs):

- System DSNs
- User DSNs